# Accessing array lists from threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, static, network-programming

I am making a multiplayer adventure game for my networking class. I have a client and a server, the server is multithreaded, and kicks off a new thread whenever it gets a new client connected. I have an array list that keeps track of the players to make sure that a new player isn't added. For some reason, when a new client connects, it takes the place of the old one as well as filling a new spot. Here is my code for this part

```
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable{
private AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel;
private static String command[];
private static String name;
private static GameCharacter character;
public ClientHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel)
{
    this.clientChannel = clientChannel;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Client Handler started for " + this.clientChannel);
        System.out.println("Messages from Client: ");
        while ((clientChannel != null) && clientChannel.isOpen()) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
            Future result = clientChannel.read(buffer);
            //Wait until buffer is ready
            result.get();
            buffer.flip();
            String message = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
            if(message == null || message.equals(""))
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(message);
            clientChannel.write(buffer);
            try {
                //Add the character to the routing table and the character table
                if (message.contains("connect")) {
                    System.out.println("I'm here too?");
                    command = message.split(" ");
                    name = command[1];
                    AdventureServer.userInfo.put(name, this);
                    //Check to see if this game character exists
                    GameCharacter test;
                    boolean exists = false;
                    for(int i=0; i < AdventureServer.characters.size(); i++)
                    {
                        test = AdventureServer.characters.get(i);
                        System.out.println(test.getName());
                        System.out.println(this.name);
                        if(this.name.equals(test.getName()))
                        {
                            System.out.println("already Here");
                            exists = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (exists == true)
                    {
                        //This person has connected to the server before
                    }
                    else {
                        //Create a game character
                        System.out.println("didn't exist before");
                        character = new GameCharacter(this.name, World.getRow(), World.getCol());
                        AdventureServer.characters.add(AdventureServer.userInfo.size() - 1, character);
                        System.out.println(AdventureServer.characters.get(0).getName() + " " +AdventureServer.characters.get(1).getName());
                    }
                }
```

I understand that the print lines at the bottom will throw an error for the first client that connects, but that is not part of the issue.
And here is the declaration of the server

```
public class AdventureServer {
public static Map<String, ClientHandler> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
public static World world;
public static List<GameCharacter> characters = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Create the games map that all of the users will exist on
    world = new World(args[0]);

    System.out.println("Asynchronous Chat Server Started");
    try {
        AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open();
        InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.7", 5000);
        serverChannel.bind(hostAddress);
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client to connect");
            Future acceptResult = serverChannel.accept();
            AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel = (AsynchronousSocketChannel) acceptResult.get();
            new Thread (new ClientHandler(clientChannel)).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error interrupted");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my constructor for game characters

```
public class GameCharacter {
public static int xpos;
public static int ypos;
private static String name;
private static int rowSize;
private static int columnSize;
static List<String> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructor
GameCharacter(String n, int rSize, int cSize)
{
    xpos = 0;
    ypos = 0;
    name = n;
    rowSize = rSize;
    columnSize = cSize;
}

GameCharacter()
{
    xpos = 0;
    ypos = 0;
    name = "billybob";
    rowSize = 10;
    columnSize = 10;
}
```

Comment: It is this line of code where things get messed up 
dventureServer.characters.add(character);

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because the fields in `ClientHandler` are static? That means every client handler shares the same character, the same name, and the same command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
public static volatile List<GameCharacter> characters = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Update:
The problem is that you are using a non synchronized HashMap userInfo.
Change that line from:

```
AdventureServer.characters.add(AdventureServer.userInfo.size() - 1, character);
```

To:

```
AdventureServer.characters.add(character);
```

Or make your HashMap Synchronized:

```
public static Map<String, ClientHandler> userInfo = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
```

All those static declarations are making problems, you should remove them. In general you should avoid using static.

ClientHandler:

```
private static String command[];
private static String name;
private static GameCharacter character;
```

GameCharacter:

```
public static int xpos;
public static int ypos;
private static String name;
private static int rowSize;
private static int columnSize;
static List<String> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
```

Just a side note, this way your Class is more like Java code should look like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GameCharacter {
private int xpos;
private int ypos;
private String name;
private int rowSize;
private int columnSize;

private List<String> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

// Constructor
GameCharacter(String n, int rSize, int cSize) {
    this.xpos = 0;
    this.ypos = 0;
    this.name = n;
    this.rowSize = rSize;
    this.columnSize = cSize;
}

GameCharacter() {
    this.xpos = 0;
    this.ypos = 0;
    this.name = "billybob";
    this.rowSize = 10;
    this.columnSize = 10;
}

public int getXpos() {
    return xpos;
}

public void setXpos(int xpos) {
    this.xpos = xpos;
}

public int getYpos() {
    return ypos;
}

public void setYpos(int ypos) {
    this.ypos = ypos;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getRowSize() {
    return rowSize;
}

public void setRowSize(int rowSize) {
    this.rowSize = rowSize;
}

public int getColumnSize() {
    return columnSize;
}

public void setColumnSize(int columnSize) {
    this.columnSize = columnSize;
}

public List<String> getInventory() {
    return inventory;
}

public void setInventory(List<String> inventory) {
    this.inventory = inventory;
}

}
```

Comment: That didn't do it unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, still broken. Its after I call the constructor that the name changes. So before I'm adding it to the arraylist

Comment: The problem is in the constructor, I just added it for you to see.

Comment: You were right, the static fields were the problem, thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of readability, testability, and style, I would also recommend you not directly access data structures belonging to another class. Instead of

```
   Adventureserver.characters.add(blah blah)
```

I would recommend making characters a private field of Adventureserver, and then creating a method to add or remove characters from it. In fact, I would be inclined not to make characters static -- there is no real advantage, and you might at some point want more than one Adventureserver running.

Sort of like so:

```
public class AdventureServer {
<...>
private List<GameCharacter> characters = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>);

<...>
public void addCharacter(GameCharacter char) {
   <... error checking ...>
   characters.add(char);
}
public void removeCharacter(GameCharacter char) {
   <... implementation ... >
}
public boolean isCharacterHere(GameCharacter char) {
}
public List<GameCharacter> getCharacters() {
  <... you could either return characters here, or a copy of it,
   depending upon how paranoid you want to be >
```

Comment: The problem is in the constructor, I just added it for you to see.